# How to get form title bar like Chrome?

Tags: winforms

Does anyone know how to get a title bar like chrome (with the tabs) using winforms (C# or VB.Net) ?

In Chrome there are different tabs in the title bar.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that is possible with forms itself but you may be interested in using a tab controller that fills the form.